# Cocos2D - Simulating infinite scrolling

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

I have a BIG problem!! I want to make something like old space shooter games like “Asteroids”, where the ship, when going out of the screen, is reappearing at the other side. For example, when the ship go out at the top of the screen, it come back at the bottom. But in my game, there’s a camera following the player, showing only a quarter of the world, and I want to simulate an infinite world this way! Here’s a picture showing what I mean :

[image: Infinite scrolling explanation]

What I thought doing was simulate the scroll by only moving game objects, stored in an array, but not the player, and calculating at every frame if the objects are out of the world boundary and re-adding them at the other end of the world (i.e going out at the left would add it back at the right).

But I don’t really like that way of doing… I’d like something more… intuitive..?

Do you guys have any idea of how doing it? Like, any tutorial on the web or just the right words to explain what I mean so I could do a bright research on google (I’m french, so I had a really hard time writing that question)!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using CCParallaxNode for infinite scrolling. There tons of stuff on the web for that. Let me know if you need some links to resources, but by googling that you should come up with bunch of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the players position, x,y check to see if the player is within the bounds of the area.  If the player has left those bounds, set the player's position to the opposite bounds, possibly adding width/height.  I'll do it here for the Y coordinate only:

```
const float minWarpAreaY( 0 );
const float maxWarpAreaY( 400 );

//if (player.y < minWarpAreaY) { player.y = maxWarpAreaY - player.height; }
//if (player.y > maxWarpAreaY) { player.y = minWarpAreaY + player.height; }

if (player.y < minWarpAreaY) { WarpPlayer(0.0f, (maxWarpAreaY - minWarpAreaY)); }
if (player.y > maxWarpAreaY) { WarpPlayer(0.0f, -(maxWarpAreaY - minWarpAreaY)); }

void WarpPlayer(float amountX, float amountY)
{
    player.x += amountX;
    player.y += amountY;

    for (eachObject in World)
    {
        eachObject.x += amountX;
        eachObject.y += amountY;
    }
}
```

Something along those lines should help.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it that way. Imagine we have an object at the edge of that said world, then the objects will disappear or appear on the screen out of nowhere (see my picture above to know what I mean!)

Comment: But is this not what would be expected if the player is warping back to some other area?

To reduce the jarring effect (very important) you could create a (really-quick (250-500ms) full screen 'warp effect'.  IE: fade the entire screen black, fade to white, (set position of player/camera), fade back black, and finally fade back to game.  The white fade could even have some swirl.  Depends if this fits or not.

(The warp effect could also be played only on the player/objects that disappear as well)

Comment: That could be a good idea, but the thing is that I want everything to be transparent, so the player doesn't notice he looped back and thinks that the world is infinite. This is a really important aspect of my game idea, I'd like to achieve it but can't think of any solution! I'm sorry I don't have any game in mind that does the exact same thing!

Comment: If your enemies/objects have motion to them, traveling toward the player, to make it completely seamless you can move the objects as well.  I've edited my answer a little bit.

However, this will make it so the player doesn't notice any movement, so you may need to check which objects you want to and don't want to move with the player.  (Such as enemies vs background objects)

Comment: Ohh yeah, haven't thought of that one! I shall try it out soon! Will let you know if it works! Thank you!